# Fabricjs - select object programatically for immediate movement/drag

Tags: javascript, dom-events, fabricjs

I am able to select object programatically using fabricjs. However, it does not behave like when one selects an object using mouse click. On a mouse click, the object comes under focus, and one can, for example, drag it. However, on programatic selection, I cannot immediately move an object. An example jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ThzXM/1/

Programmatic selection:

```
canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
```

What I would like to ultimately achieve is this: **on clicking a button, a new rectangle is added to canvas, which the user can move around before placing it on canvas - without requiring extra clicks**. Is it possible to do this in a cross-browser compatible way? (I know in some browsers I can fire a mouseclick event but most disallow it.)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue, newly added items even though they look active cannot be interacted with until they are deselected and reselected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this. Don´t forget to call setCoords() to update the bounding box of your object.

```
// Set the active element
canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
// Set left, o right,or angle... check documentation.
//Don´t forget to call setCoords() after changes.
canvas.item(0).setLeft(80).setCoords(); 
//Then render the canvas
canvas.renderAll()
```